# Can a test case find more than one bug?

Tags: testing

I'm studying measurement of good quality test case through Effective & Efficient.

Effective: it finds a high percentage of existing bugs. 
60 test cases -> 60 bugs is better than 60 test cases -> 30 bugs.

Efficient: it has a high rate of success (bugs found/test cases).
20 test cases -> 8 bugs is better than 40 test cases -> 8 bugs.

Then it got me thinking, is it possible for a single test case to find multiple bugs? If so, can you give an example? May be for a program that do summation of two integer values.

For me, I think it's impossible because each test case only have one expected value, thus it only aims to uncover a single bug.

Comment: But couldn't different *wrong* values indicate *different* bugs?

Comment: @ScottHunter Suppose a test case that checks summation of two positive integers is correct or not `(1 + 1 == 2)`. So, these two different bugs you meant is when the programs do `1 + 1 != 2` and `1 + 2 != 3`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, you can have multiple asserts on different things.  But is it desirable ?  That's a different question.   A good test case tests one thing and only one thing.  And don't forget that a test does not test for bugs - it tests that functionality works as expected.  A given functionality may fail for multiple reasons.  For example, a loop might fail because of a counter that is not incremented, an incorrect exit condition, or some other reason.

Here are 2 more measures for you :

- Does the test enable rapid identification of the problem.  Don't
  forget that tests are not just run on new code, but are also run to
  check that a modification has not broken existing code.   You could
  put all your tests into a single mega-test, but then if the test
  failed you would not know what was broken.
- Is the test tolerant of    code modification?  Will the test need to
  be re-written when I modify    code being tested ?     If I make
  minor changes to my object under    test I don't want to rewrite all
  my tests.